# About security in PHP-MYSQL

Tags: php, security, session, variables

Please apologize my english.

In my website I use this kind of lines to define if the current user is an admin or a normal user:

```
<? if($_SESSION["nivel"] == 'administrator'){ ?>
```

I wanna know if this $_SESSION variable could be modified from client side by an user and cause me some security problems.

Comment: No, it can't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is a superglobal which is only modified on the server.

Therefore the client will never be able to change it.

Src: http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php

[Is it possible to change a $_SESSION variable client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912223/is-it-possible-to-change-a-session-variable-client-side)