# PHP, Google Authentication and need to check validity of access_token on every page

Tags: php, google-oauth, access-token, google-auth-library

I am a bit confused. I am playing around with Google Authentication in PHP. I have a index.php page which only has the link to my Google Authentication page which is called google-auth.php and is responsible for the authentication an receiving the access token. After successful authentication the user in being redirected to a welcome.php page. Both files look like this.

**index.php**

```
<a href="google-auth.php" class="field google">
<img src="images/google.png" alt="" class="google-img">
<span>Login with Google</span>
```

**google-auth.php**

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('...');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/php_google_login/index.php');
$client->addScope('email');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
    $oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $userInfo = $oauth->userinfo->get();

    $email = $userInfo->email;
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];
    $user = new User();
    $_SESSION['user_db_id'] = $user->getIdByEmail($email);

    header("Location: welcome.php");
    exit();
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

So far it works. When i open index.php i am being redirected to the Google Authentication page. I type in my email address and being successfully redirected to welcome.php. It queries the database for the user id and stores it in a sesion variable (assumption is that the user exist or is being created by any mechanism).

But now the question how to secure the welcome.php or all other pages in my sandbox? Can i trust the $_SESSION variable? Cant it be "modified"? Or do i need to check on each page additionally the existence of the $_SESSION["access_token"] variable and check with Google_Client its validity?

I have found on the Google Documentation something like this, from my understanding validates the token:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.

$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
  $userid = $payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}
```

I am confused what would be best practice. What is trustworthy and unchangeable in terms of variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change a $\_SESSION variable client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912223/is-it-possible-to-change-a-session-variable-client-side)

Comment: Yes and no.  When i got it correct, i can put the "isAuthenticated" after successful authentication in SESSION variable and from a security perspective it would be sufficient just to check whether is still available. So a simple check for $_SESSION["isAuth"] == true should be fine after an initial Google Auth process. But if $_SESSION == false or NULL or something else, i would redirect to the Google Authentication page.